# How to test dynamically named inputs inside ng-repeat using $setViewValue()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-ng-repeat, karma-runner

I am trying to test a directive that dynamically adds form inputs to a page using ng-repeat. The code runs fine in the browser but trying to test it with Jasmine I discovered what seems (to me) to be a bug or at least weird behaviour in Angular.

I'd expect to be able to set the view value on an input using

```
form.questions.answer1.$setViewValue();
```

but in my tests when I console log the form.questions object I get this:

```
form.questions.answer{{ question.questionId }}
```

i.e. The index of the object hasn't been parsed (although the html is output correctly).

Is there any other way of triggering the ng-change event? I have tried setting the value of the input using jQuery (inside my test) but although it successfully changes the value it doesn't fire off the ng-change event.

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8sDzrU?p=preview)** (check the contents of your console to see what I mean.).

My code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
app.directive('repeatedInputs', function(){
  var template ='<div  ng-form name="questions">'+
  '<div ng-repeat="(key, question) in questions" >' +                                                   
    '<span id="question{{ question.questionId }}">{{ question.questionText }}</span>'+
    '<span><input type="text" name="answer{{ question.questionId }}"' +
     ' id="answer{{question.questionId}}"' +                                                                  
    '  ng-model="question.answer" ng-change="change()"/></span>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

  return {                                                                                                                             
      template: template,
      scope: {
        answers: '=',
        singleAnswer: '='
      },

      /**                                                                                                                                
       * Links the directive to the view.                                                                                                
       *                                                                                                                                 
       * @param {object} scope                                                                                                           
       * Reference to the directive scope.                                                                                               
       *                                                                                                                                 
       * @param {object} elm                                                                                                             
       * Reference to the directive element.                                                                                             
       */                                                                                                                                
      link: function (scope, element) {                                                                                                  

        scope.questions = [
          {
            questionId: '1',
            questionText: 'What is your name?',
            answer: null
          },
          { 
            questionId: '2',
            questionText: 'What is your quest?',
            answer: null
          },
          { 
            questionId: '3',
            questionText: 'What is your favourite colour?',
            answer: null
          }
        ];

        scope.change = function () {
          for (var i in scope.questions) {
            scope.answers[i] = scope.questions[i].answer;
          }
        };
      }
   };
});
```

Here is my spec file:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
describe('repeating inputs directive', function () {                           

  var element, scope, $compile;                                                                     

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('plunker');
    inject(function ($rootScope, _$compile_) {                   

      scope = $rootScope.$new();                                                  
      scope.theAnswers = [];
      scope.singleAnswer = null;

      element = angular.element(                                                  
        '<form name="form">'
        +'<div repeated-inputs answers="theAnswers" single-answer="singleAnswer">'
        +'</div></form>'                 
      );                                                                          
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$apply();
    })
  });

  it('should store the input from the answers in the parent scope',             
      function () {                                                             

    // I want to do this
    //scope.form.questions.answer1.$setViewValue('Ben');

    // but inside the object, the answers name field is not being parsed
    // I am expecting the path to the answer to look like this:
    // scope.form.questions.answer1
    // instead it looks like this:
    // scope.form.questions.answer{{ question.questionId }}
    console.log(scope.form.questions);

    expect(scope.theAnswers[0]).toEqual('Ben');

  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found out that what I was trying to do is currently impossible in Angular. The only way to test this is using a web browser - I have a protractor test for this piece of functionality now.

Interpolated names (for ngModel) are not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
elementScope = $compile(element)(scope).isolateScope();
...
expect(elementScope.theAnswers[0]).toEqual('Ben');
```

Since an isolated scope will be created for the directive due to:

```
 scope: {
        answers: '=',
        singleAnswer: '='
      }
```

Comment: The problem is actually that the change event is not triggered unless you use "$setViewValue" on the form input. You can set the value directly in the scope, but you are unable to test things like validation using unit tests without being able to trigger the change event programatically.